# How to filter meta-tags in json response with Python Requests?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, meta-tags

I have the following code with the Matchbook betting API.

```
r17 = s.get('https://matchbook.com/bpapi/rest/events/?sport-ids=15&?after=1486157894&?before=14862442917&')
data1 = r17.json()

for event in data1['events']:
    print(event['name'])
    print(event['id'])
    print(event['sport-id'])
    print(event['start'])
    print(event['meta-tags'])
```

which gives the following json output

```
Bayern Munich vs Schalke
368063
15
2017-02-04T14:35:00.000Z
[{'id': 1, 'url-name': 'sport', 'name': 'Sport', 'type': 'UNKNOWN'}, {'id': 402, 'url-name': 'live-betting', 'name': 'Live Betting', 'type': 'COMPETITION'}, {'id': 4, 'url-name': 'soccer', 'name': 'Soccer', 'type': 'SPORT'}, {'id': 56, 'url-name': 'germany', 'name': 'Germany', 'type': 'COUNTRY'}, {'id': 57, 'url-name': 'bundesliga', 'name': 'Bundesliga', 'type': 'COMPETITION'}, {'id': 4105, 'url-name': 'february-4th-2017', 'name': 'February 4th 2017', 'type': 'DATE'}]
```

The meta-tags are contained between the [] brackets. How do I filter by these meta-tags?

Comment: You want to sort all items in `event['meta-tags']` by `id` or by `name`?

Comment: Yeah I guess by id or name - either would work! If I knew how to do one I could do the other right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pprint

r17 = requests.get('https://matchbook.com/bpapi/rest/events/?sport-ids=15&?after=1486157894&?before=14862442917&')
data = r17.json()

for event in data['events']:
    print(event['name'])
    pprint.pprint(event['meta-tags'], indent=4)
    print('sorted:')
    # change k['id'] to k['name'] if you need to sort dict's by name
    pprint.pprint(sorted(event['meta-tags'], key=lambda k: k['id']), indent=4)
```

Comment: so I have this: [   {   'allow-live-betting': False,
        'back-overround': 101.86094,
        'event-id': 401762468800010,
        'id': 401762469550010,
        'in-running-flag': False,
        'lay-overround': 99.99578,
        'market-type': 'outright_ded_fact',
        'name': 'WIN',
        'runners': [   {   'event-id': 401762468800010,
                           'event-participant-id': 401762469360010,
                           'id': 401762469590010,
                           'market-id': 401762469550010,
                           'name': '1 Mystique Moon',

Comment: why can't I sort that by runners?

Comment: @Davtho1983 `runners` it is `list` of `dicts`. you can use the same way for sorting `runners`